# Using JMeter's Regular Expression Extractor, where does the output get saved?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using the Regular Expression Extractor to extract an authentication code which I need to use in the following `JMeter Sampler` in my test. This code is saved in the response Header as Authentication: `djdjf...##` (a bunch of letters and numbers followed by ##).

In the Regular Expression Extractor "Field to check" I selected the "Response Headers" radio button.

Then I entered:

> Reference Name: Auth
>
> Regular Expression: \A\w*==\z
>
> Template: $1$
>
> Match No. (0 for random): 1
>
> Default Value: NOT FOUND

Where do the results from the Regular Expression Extractor execution get saved?

I was hoping the results would get saved in a User Defined Variable, defined as Auth in my Test Plan's User Defined Variable section, but if I enter Auth in the "Reference Name" of the Regular Expression Extractor, and run JMeter, Auth never gets populated.

Comment: You select the template as `$1$`, but do not use capturing groups inside the regex. Try `\A(\w*==)\z` if you want the whole value to be captured.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a separate `User Defined variable` for this. The name you give in the Reference name field will be used as a variable to store the match found using the regular expression pattern.

So, To access the value, just use `${Auth}`. It should give the `result` from regular expression or `NOT FOUND`

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helps.

Comment: @keithscarr, if you think this answered your question, you can accept this as an answer by clicking on the tick sign.

Answer (score 1):

Very Easy and Simple way is:-

After Regular Expression Extractor put Debug Post Processor.

1- Right click on your request where you already created Regular Exp -> Add -> Post processor -> Debug PostProcessor

2- In Debug PostProcessor at the place of name give the variable name which you taken for extract, like  ${Name}

3- Now in Listener part after test run you will get the Exact Value which is passed in regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses Perl5-style regular expressions via [Jakarta ORO](http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-oro.html).

You can use [ORO demonstration applet](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/oro/trunk/docs/demo.html) or [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to [debug your regular expression](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

I would suggest to substitute your "Regular Expression" with something as simple as `Authentication: (.*)` keeping other fields as they are.

Once extracted you should be able to refer extracted header as `${Auth}` or `${__V(Auth)}` where required.

Declaring "Auth" variable via User Defined Variables is not mandatory, it will be created in the Regular Expression Extractor.